# How to blur drawing using the DrawingContext (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, blur

MSDN says, that one may apply blur bitmap effect do stuff drawn by the `DrawingContext` using the `PushEffect` method. But, both `PushEffect` and `*BitmapEffect`s are marked as obsolete.

How may I apply blur to what is drawn by the DrawingContext?

Comment: could you share some code here? perhaps the xaml part of the container.

Comment: *There is no Xaml*. I'm doing it all in OnRender of my custom control.

Comment: I wonder what kind of "custom control" you're doing that requires `OnRender()`?

Comment: do you want to blur whole render or just a part of it?

Comment: You might perhaps use the [UIElement.Effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.effect.aspx) property instead.

Comment: @pushpraj Only some elements.

Comment: @Clemens How can I use `UIElement.Effect` to blur a single rectangle drawn using the `DrawingContext`? (among dozens of non-blurred items)

Comment: @HighCore Why does it matter?  Maybe like me, he wants to show a heatmap data visualisation making use of WPF's hardware acceleration so that he can pan and zoom full screen at 30 FPS sans stuttering, something that I found the [Drawing Visual technique](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254(v=vs.110).aspx) was too slow to achieve.

Comment: @MickyD because this is from around mid 2014, and around that time, I was very active on stackoverflow calling people out for using WPF with a winforms mentality. I've moved past since then.

Comment: @HighCore That's fine, I did note the date.  I come across people saying stuff like that today (like with WPF-gaming).  Anyway, thanks for the clarification. Wishing you well :)

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

in the constructor of your `UserControl` set the `Effect` property to an instance of `BlurEffect` and that would blur the whole render.

```
    public UserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Effect = new BlurEffect() { Radius = 10 };
    }
```

**Selective Blur**

I attempted to achieve selective blur by leveraging [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap) class

I've created an extension method for simplified usage

`Extension class`

```
public static class DrawingContextExtension
{
    public static void RenderBlurred(this DrawingContext dc, int width, int height, Rect targetRect, double blurRadius, Action<DrawingContext> action)
    {
        Rect elementRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
        BlurredElement element = new BlurredElement(action)
        {
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            Effect = new BlurEffect() { Radius = blurRadius }
        };
        element.Arrange(elementRect);
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
        rtb.Render(element);
        dc.DrawImage(rtb, targetRect);
    }

    class BlurredElement : FrameworkElement
    {
        Action<DrawingContext> action;
        public BlurredElement(Action<DrawingContext> action)
        {
            this.action = action;
        }
        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            base.OnRender(drawingContext);
            action(drawingContext);
        }
    }
}
```

example code

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        int boxSize = 20;

        Pen pen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                Rect targetRect = new Rect(i * boxSize, j * boxSize, boxSize, boxSize);
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Rect elementRect = new Rect(0, 0, boxSize, boxSize);
                    double blurRadius = 5;
                    drawingContext.RenderBlurred(boxSize, boxSize, targetRect, blurRadius, dc => dc.DrawRectangle(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent), pen, elementRect));
                }
                else
                {
                    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent), pen, targetRect);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

result

[image: result]

in above example rectangles in every odd row is blurred

Comment: I don't want to blur everything, only some elements of the drawing.

Comment: In that case we can have a workaround to render the stuff to an element and apply the blur to it and then render the blurred element to the user control. [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap) can help us here. let me try to code a sample for you.

Comment: Souldn't your constructor `public BlurredElement(Action<DrawingContext> action)` be `public Placeholder(Action<DrawingContext> action)` :)

Comment: Great `SelectiveBlur`!  I realise this was 2014 but did you ever run into _"[RenderTargetBitmap throws MILERR_WIN32ERROR](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806996/wpf-wic-rendertargetbitmap-throws-milerr-win32error-gdi-handles)"_?  It happens to me when I attempt to draw 200+ items using `RenderBlurred`

Comment: @MickyD, I think I never hit this error, perhaps never crossed the limits.